# C# Generic Class field possible

Tags: c#, generics

I am new to C# (Java developer), I want to have a class field that is a generic list, actually it is a dictionary of lists:

```
protected IDictionary<String, IList<Object>> filters;
```

I have code that sets

```
public void SetFilters(String key, params Object[] values) {
    if (key == null || values == null) {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("Must have filter name and values.");
    }
    if (filters == null) filters = new Dictionary<String, IList<Object>>();
    IList<Object> fvalues = values.ToList();
    filters.Add(key, fvalues);         
}
```

But when my code tries to retrieve and cast the `IList<Object>` back to `IList<String>` or `IList<int>` I get an InvalidCastException.

I thought I would make the list generic:

```
protected IDictionary<String, IList<T>> filters; //does not complile

protected IDictionary<String, IList<T>> filters  where T: Object;//does not compile either
```

I cannot make the class generic since the dictionary will have lists of `Strings` or `int`. In Java, `Integer` and `Strings` are all `Objects`, so this was not an issue with `IList<? extends Object>`.

Thanks!

Comment: Just use a non generic list, `IDictionary<String, IList> filters`, instead.

Comment: you probably need casting: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx

Comment: You can make the list generic but you would also have to make the containing class generic to be able to set the generic type. So to use `protected IDictionary<String, IList<T>> filters;` you would need `public class MyClass<T>` as well.

Comment: Also what is your code to do the casting to `IList<string>`? How does it know to do `string` rather than `int`? It would be useful to see more of the big picture to properly help you out here.

Comment: Using IList without generics worked. Though I am still wondering how to have this for future situations.

Comment: It works, but how do you know when a list holds strings and when it holds ints?

Comment: Chris, The bigger picture is part of an application configuration which allows for filters to be specified. It is an abstract (base) class that the subclasses then set the list to the appropriate type. I also forsee the need to use something like: `IList<? extends MyAbstractClass>` type for future. If a class can cast `IList<MyAbstractClass>` to `IList<Subclass1>` or `IList<Subclass2>`. I think covariance makes this possible without casting. But since int and String are not Objects in C# I am unable to make it work in this situation. Correct?

Comment: `But since int and String are not Objects in C# I am unable to make it work in this situation` - Why not create something similar to `IFilter` then create `StringFilter:IFilter` or `NumericFilter:IFilter`. You then do something similar to `protected IDictionary<String, IList<IFilter>> filters;` - Each `IFilter` implementation knows how to deal with the values and could have a `Filter` method. You might even then be able to go further and make  `public YourClass : IFilterable<IList<IFilter>>` in which methods inside can use methods of `IFilter` - Or similar. - Just brainstorming :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `System.Collection.IList`, similar to this:

```
public class Foo
{
    public IDictionary<String, IList> filters;
    public void SetFilters(String key, params object[] values)
    {
        if (key == null || values == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Must have filter name and values.");
        }

        if (filters == null)
        {
            filters = new Dictionary<String, IList>();
        }

        IList fvalues = values.ToList();
        filters.Add(key, fvalues);
    }
}
```

You could then use it like this:

```
var foo = new Foo();

foo.SetFilters("Key1", 1,2,3);
foo.SetFilters("Key2", "a","b","c");
foo.SetFilters("Key3", new {a = 1, b = 2}, new {c = 1, d = 2});
```

You still have then the issue of casting back each list type into the expected type when accessing and using it.

---

[**DEMO**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wocr4H) - Using `IList`

---

Comment: I seem to be missing the way to convert the IList to IList<string> (or IList<String>) for "Key2". I am getting a cast exception. Very cool dotnetfiddle.net! https://dotnetfiddle.net/r7D9BL is the code I tried with help from Grax's similar answer.

Answer (score 0):

Does it help? I created a new generic class.

```
internal class Program
{
    private class Reed<T>
    {
        private IDictionary<String, IList<T>> filters;
        public void SetFilters(String key, params T[] values)
        {
            if (key == null || values == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Must have filter name and values.");
            }

            if (filters == null)
                filters = new Dictionary<String, IList<T>>();
            IList<T> fvalues = values.ToList();
            filters.Add(key, fvalues);
        }
    }

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var r1 = new Reed<string>();
        r1.SetFilters("test", "one", "two", "three");
        var r2 = new Reed<int>();
        r2.SetFilters("test", 1, 2, 3);
    }
}
```

Comment: This design allows the dictionary to only hold lists of the same type. If I understood OP correctly the requirement seems that the one dictionary should be able to hold a list any type. i.e: `filters.add('key1', new List<string>())` as well as `filters.add('key2', new List<int>())`

Comment: I am trying to have the Dictionary have keys that hold lists of different types. For example, `SetFilter("names","name1","name2"); ` and `SetFilter("idnumbers", 2,3);` Making it non-generic helped.

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid the error casting, you need to create a typed list in the first place.  To do that you should use a generic.

For the dictionary item type, you can use IList or object but you will need to store a strongly typed list as the item value.

If you make SetFilters a generic method, then it can make a properly typed list to store in the dictionary.  I included a GetFilters method that returns the list that matches the key. i.e. values.ToList() will create a `List<T>`

```
public class FilterManager
{
    protected IDictionary<String, IList> filters = new Dictionary<string, IList>();

    public void SetFilters<T>(String key, params T[] values)
    {
        if (key == null || values == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Must have filter name and values.");
        }

        IList fvalues = values.ToList();
        filters.Add(key, fvalues);
    }

    public IList<T> GetFilters<T>(string key)
    {
        return (IList<T>)filters[key];
    }
}
```

Call it like this

```
var filterManager = new FilterManager();
filterManager.SetFilters("MyIntegerFilters", 3, 4, 5);
filterManager.SetFilters("MyStringFilters", "A", "B", "C");

var intFilters = filterManager.GetFilters<int>("MyIntegerFilters");
var stringFilters = filterManager.GetFilters<string>("MyStringFilters");
```

You will get an exception if you call

```
var filters = filterManager.GetFilters<int>("MyStringFilters");
```

because it will try to convert a `List<string>` to a `List<int>`

Comment: This looks promising; however, an exception is thrown : [System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[System.String]'.] from GetFilters() return/cast statement.

Comment: Are you using a variable of type `object` for your parameters?  You should be using variables of type int or string.  If you use only parameters of type int (except for the first string key parameter), it should create a list of int and if you use only parameters of type `string` then it should create a list of string.

Comment: You can also try giving SetFilters the type explicitly.  `filterManager.SetFilters<int>("MyIntegerFilters",3,4,5)`